# How to create select dropdown in javaScript with fetched data from api

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, async-await, fetch-api

In this code I am not able to create the select option. After fetching the API the data should get displayed as the option of the select dropdown and this `for loop` is not getting executed.

```
const batchTrack = document.getElementById("#batchSelect");
console.log(batchTrack);
const getPost = async () => {
const response = await fetch("http://eltp-coditas.cloudjiffy.net/batch/");
console.log(response);
const data = response.json();
return data;
};

const displayOption = async () => {
const options = await getPost();
for (option of Object.keys(options)) {
const newOption = document.createElement("option");
console.log(option);
newOption.value = option;
newOption.text = option.name;
batchTrack.appendChild(newOption);
}
};
displayOption();
```

Comment: Please format your code snippet.

Comment: Are the console.log() inside for loop not printing at all? Can you check if console.log(options) printswhat you expect.

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove # in  `document.getElementById("#batchSelect");`
2. Add await for `await response.json();` because `json()` is a async function.

After all fix, it should work.

**Example below**

```js
const batchTrack = document.getElementById("batchSelect");
console.log({ batchTrack });
const getPost = async () => {
  const response = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users");
  const data = await response.json();
  return data;
};

const displayOption = async () => {
  const options = await getPost();
  for (option of options) {
    const newOption = document.createElement("option");
    newOption.value = option.username;
    newOption.text = option.name;
    batchTrack.appendChild(newOption);
  }
};

displayOption();
```

```html
<select id="batchSelect"></select>
```

Comment: Did you bother testing your code in the snippet tool? The data doesn't display.

Comment: @Millhorn, It is because the endpoint `http://eltp-coditas.cloudjiffy.net/batch/` is removed from the OP.

Comment: @Millhorn, I updated to a new endpoint for demo purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You have couple errors in your code:

- `getElementById("#batchSelect");` You don't need to use `#` in this function
- Your response object has `data` property that contains the array. So you can loop thru the data array.
- In your response, objects don't have property called `name` but `batchName`

**HTML:**

```
<select id="batchSelect"></select>
```

**Script Block:**

```
const batchTrack = document.getElementById("batchSelect");
const getPost = async () => {
    const response = await fetch("http://eltp-coditas.cloudjiffy.net/batch/");
    console.log(response);
    const data = response.json();
    return data;
};

    const displayOption = async () => {
        const options = await getPost();
        options.data.forEach(option => {
    
            const newOption = document.createElement("option");
            console.log(option);
            newOption.value = option.batchName;
            newOption.text = option.batchName;
            batchTrack.appendChild(newOption);
    
        });
    };
    displayOption();
```

Answer (score -1):

this will help you.try this [URL](https://www.codebyamir.com/blog/populate-a-select-dropdown-list-with-json)

```
    let dropdown = document.getElementById('locality-dropdown');
dropdown.length = 0;

let defaultOption = document.createElement('option');
defaultOption.text = 'Choose State/Province';

dropdown.add(defaultOption);
dropdown.selectedIndex = 0;

const url = 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/7xq2x';

    fetch(url)  
      .then(  
        function(response) {  
          if (response.status !== 200) {  
            console.warn('Looks like there was a problem. Status Code: ', 
              response.status);  
            return;  
          }
    
          // Examine the text in the response  
          response.json().then(function(data) {  
            let option;
        
            for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
              option = document.createElement('option');
              option.text = data[i].name;
              option.value = data[i].abbreviation;
              dropdown.add(option);
            }    
          });  
        }  
      )  
      .catch(function(err) {  
        console.error('Fetch Error -', err);  
      });
```

Comment: Please add the relevant code here. The link might break in future, making it irrelevant and not useful for people who will come in later.

Comment: You can leave a comment instead.

Comment: check it out now. is that ok? @TusharShahi

Comment: Yes. Add more details as to why you think this would work. That would help anyone facing the issue.